# How to get a list of files from TFS from a specified date?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, tfs

I have a Visual Studio 2010 C# project in TFS. I want to download all files from TFS above a certain date.

What is the best approach to do this using the TFS API in C#?
What i have done: get all the project items from TFS, for each item check check-in date and download it. Unfortunately, i have a lot of these files and it takes a long time to download them all and then filtering them by a date.

My code:

```
var tfs = RegisteredTfsConnections.GetProjectCollection(new Uri("MyTfsUri"));
var projects = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(tfs);
var versionControl = (VersionControlServer)projects.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
ItemSet itemsSqlScripts = versionControl.GetItems("Path in TFS", RecursionType.Full);

foreach (var item in itemsSqlScripts.Items)
{
                if (item.CheckinDate > date)
                {
                    item.DownloadFile("C:\\SqlScripts\\" + Path.GetFileName(item.ServerItem));
                }
}
```

And i want to something like this:

```
ItemSet itemsSqlScripts = versionControl.GetItems("Path in TFS", RecursionType.Full, and here parameter filter -> for example new DateTime(2015, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

I watched and read about:

```
tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>().QueryHistory(...)
```

but i have no idea how to use this function to do what i want :(

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
DateTime targetDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
string downloadLocation;

var changes = versionControl.QueryHistory(
            "$/MyProject",
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            0,
            RecursionType.Full,
            null,
            new DateVersionSpec(targetDate),
            VersionSpec.Latest,
            int.MaxValue,
            true,
            false);

foreach (Changeset changeset in changes)
{
    foreach (var change in changeset.Changes.Where(c => c.Item.ItemType == ItemType.File))
    {
        change.Item.DownloadFile(downloadLocation + change.Item.ServerItem.Substring(2));
    }                                
}
```